# how to access image data in Elm?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, elm

How do we get the Pixel data from images in Elm?

---

Here in JavaScript, is code to get the color of a set of pixels in a figure (taken from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/42b6096fe66e978a3b77))

```
var image = new Image;
image.src = "starry-night.jpg";

var canvas  = d3.select("body").append("canvas");
var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

// beware variable name "image" got used twice
image = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

var x = Math.random()*width,
    y = Math.random()*height,
    i = (y * width + x) << 2;

pixelColor = d3.rgb(image.data[i + 0], image.data[i + 1], image.data[i + 2]) + "";
```

The code loads an image to a `<canvas>` element, then extracts the color of a pixel from the canvas using `image.getImageData()`.

**Can we interface the `image.data` object in Elm?**  Right now I don't think it's possible...

- Right now [`Collage`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-graphics/1.0.0/Collage) types are list of forms...
- [`HTML`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.0.0/Html) is also a module that can put imags in the DOM.
- [`SVG`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/svg/1.0.0/Svg) allows for some simple global image transformations but nothing at the pixel level

Elm has the [Virtual Dom](http://elm-lang.org/blog/blazing-fast-html).  In fact of problems like this, might be addressed in [`virtual-dom`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/virtual-dom/1.0.2/) which is lower level so we are not encouraged to do this directly.

However, Elm makes a clear distinction between `Collage` elements and `SVG` elements, with no clear interface to the [`getImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) function.

- Do I write my own with Elm's new [interOp](http://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html) feature?
- Does a way already exist in Elm?  Or a new one has to be written?

---

#### JavaScript

- The [<<](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) operator is called `Left Shift`

Comment: Evan is working his way through the HTML5 spec and enabling the native functions in Elm, but fear this one is not high on his list. In the meantime I would suggest you use a Port to transmit the values to Elm

Comment: @SimonH I am tempted to fork `Collage` and add the function myself https://github.com/evancz/elm-graphics/tree/1.0.0/src or maybe [ports](http://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/) may be a good way of prototyping this.  And I can pull-request, even if my solution is completely wrong!

Comment: @johnmangual - you are probably best off using ports instead of submitting a change to `Collage`. The `getImageData()` function seems beyond the scope of something that can be gleaned from VirtualDOM, and more like something that the browser has to provide.

Comment: @ChadGilbert html5 is humungous and Evan is working hard, I'm sure.  It might require adding some native JS code as well as an Elm method.  Since `getImageData()` implied at some point I created a `new Image()`  and then [`drawImage()`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp). So I guess can subscribe Elm to call this in JS.

Comment: It would be good to know why you would want to do this? I can imagine a solution, where you create a custom element that loads the image and sends the data to your Elm app in the form of whatever message you want it in, and then you can process it in your `update`. (I think you cannot get it nicer than that because of how the browser API is.) But why would you want to do that anyway, since Elm does not have good support for binary data?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @SimonH, use a port to JS until Elm provides a first-hand way to do so (if it ever does). The same approach would apply to anything you can't yet do in Elm.

I'm just answering as an answer rather than a comment for the sake of others who come here.